# Return distinct matching and non-matching rows (outer join?)

Tags: sql, oracle

I know I've done this in the past and I can't think of the solution now... I know it's some sort of full outer join.

I've got 3 tables:

```
ACTIVITIES       
id   name        
---+-------------
1  |  Basketball 
2  |  Chess Club 

ENROLLMENT                   
id   activity_id   person_id 
---+-------------+-----------
1  | 1           | 1         
2  | 1           | 2         
3  | 2           | 1         

ATTENDANCE
id   date         person_id   activity_id
---+-------------+----------+---------------
1  | 2017-01-01  | 1        | 1
2  | 2017-01-01  | 2        | 1
3  | 2017-01-02  | 1        | 1
```

I'm trying to get attendance by `person_id`, even when that id doesn't exist for a date:

```
date          person_id
------------+---------------
2017-01-01  | 1
2017-01-02  | null
```

Here's something close to what I think I'll need...

```
select date, attendance.person_id
from enrollment
**SOME SORT OF JOIN** attendance on enrollment.person_id = attendance.person_id
where person_id = 1
```

But all I can get returned is:

```
date          person_id
------------+---------------
2017-01-01  | 1
2017-01-01  | 1
```

...where the number of rows is correct but the values are wrong.

Comment: @yılmaz because it would be joined with enrollment, where the `person_id` exists and by `activity_id` my psuedo query doesn't quite justify it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would seem to result in the results you want:

```
select date,
       max(case when person_id = 1 then person_id end) as person_id
from attendance a
group by date
order by date;
```